# HTML iFrame positioning

Tags: html, iframe

Here is a link to the code about this question: http://virtual.weltec.ac.nz/s13/blog/blog.html

Basically, I am wanting to move my iFrame in such a way as to align it under my CSS menu bar. What is the best way to do this? Is there such a thing as a 'coordinate' tag to position it exactly where I want it, or some other way?

thanks

Comment: You can improve that page by keeping all the styles in a single style block in the `<head>`.  You can make it better than that by putting all the styles into a separate CSS file and importing it with a `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you had it displaying as block element?

```
ul, iframe{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Actually very easy, I just had to add a few <br> statements.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. However, you really should look into CSS positioning in general.